# Remove zero eigenvalues (or any) by deleting rows and columns and other eigenvalues unchanged

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to remove $k$ zero eigenvalues of a matrix by removing $k$ rows and columns of a square matrix (after modification using decomposition methods or other ways) with other eigenvalues unchanged?. If so, how to identify the rows and column to be removed?

Major problem is the loss of sparsity on modified matrix

PS: A simple understanding is, with one zero eigenvalue, there is one dependent row and column in the matrix. Then the dependent row/column can be written as a linear combination of other rows/columns and can be used to reduce the dimension using a transformation. But not sure the eigenvalues invariability and how to choose the the dependent row/column (there will be multiple possibility).

Answer (score 1):

No. 
Let $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}2 & 2\\2 & 2\end{array}\right]$. This matrix has eigenvalues $0$ and $4$.

Comment: It is possible using deflation techniques. shift the matrix with eigenvalue 4 so that 0 eigenvalue is -4. Then use deflation method to remove a column and vector. In MATLAB the procedure is,
`%Matrix
A=[2, 2; 2, 2];

[v,l]=eigs(A,1);
A=A-l*eye(2,2);
[v,l]=eigs(A,1);
[~,p]=max(v);

%deflation
A1=A-v/v(p)*A(p,:);
%removal of row and column
A1(p,:)=[];
A1(:,p)=[];

[v,l]=eigs(A1,1);`

Comment: You allowed only for column and row deletion, but your code modifies also diagonal entries. .

Comment: Simply removing a column and row will not do the job. I know that. But after some modification, this will happen. You are right on my question. I missed to add "remove column and row after modification"